# Install gvim (vi app from gvim.org) from PowerShell silently

Tags: powershell, vim

How can you quietly install gvim80-586.exe (version 80 of the self installable vi app from vim.org) from PowerShell silently?

We're building a process to automate setting up a Windows 10 computer to a reference (e.g. turn on Remote Desktop access, turn off notifications, etc.) and would like to install gvim as one of the base applications using a script but the current (gvim version 80) self installable requires user input. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the http://vim.org website.

Perhaps it's possible to contain the installation in such a way as to answer the input questions of the installer automatically.

Comment: What is `gvim80-586.exe`? No context at all in this question. Yet, as an advice when trying to do such things either use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or look there for your respected package's implementation on how the silent installer works.

Comment: there isn't any documentation in vim.org on installing it silently so I thought there may be an undocumented way. can't use chocolatey because the process is done offline. I'll try to reword the question. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, take a look in the implementation of the [package on chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vim) and then you will probably see how they do it. Otherwise you are stuck with the cmdline and the various help arguments e.g. `/h`,`/help`,'-h`,'--help` etc

Comment: You might also identify the type of the install engine that they are using and then look into that engine's documentation.

Comment: I see what you're trying to tell me now, "look at how chocolatey does it". Will do. Thanks